# Chi Square Test for a Pre/Post True False 8 question test

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have an eight question Pre and Post, True or False test, taken by 172 participants. Is it appropriate to use a Chi Square test in the following manner?

```
         # Correct Responses       # Incorrect Responses

PreTest               1327                     209

PostTest              1472                     64
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can run a [chi square test of homogeneity](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/tests_of_proportions.html).

Comment: The assumptions of the $\chi^2$ test don't seem likely to apply, @Antoni, because we ought to expect dependence among the responses within each group of eight questions answered by any single participant.

Comment: @whuber I was thinking that, and I talked myself out of it... The right answer is probably a McNemar test... but the contingency table doesn't have the typical matching diagonal of concordant pre- and post...

Answer (score 1):

As @whuber pointed out, and can be found on Chapter 9 Models for Matched Pairs of Agresti's An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis, the responses when a *natural pairing* exists (in this case, the same subjects with pre- and post-testing) are *statistically dependent*.

The data can be presented in a 2 x 2 square contingency table with the same categories. In the case of the OP, it would entail matching for each subject so that you can count the number of questions answered correctly both before and after the test, incorrectly both before and after, correctly before but incorrectly after, and incorrectly before but correctly after.

In the OP the data provided would really be the marginal counts of this matched table:

```
           pre_test
post_test   crrt incorr     Sum
  crrct      a       b      1472
  incorr     c       d      64
  Sum      1327    209      1536
```

In a McNemar test the null hypothesis is that $a + b = a + c$, or $b = c$; in other words, equality in the counts or proportions in the off-diagonal.

Comment: With apologies for my initial, quick but misguided comment/response.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the raw data to determine per participant which responses are matched.  Are there any other tests that might be appropriate given that I do not have the match information?